# iOS: UI Assets missing options and sizes

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode8, assets

I'm trying to create an new asset catalog for universal project (iPhone and iPad). I add new xcassest:

[image]
But As you can see in case of iPhone only shows one option for 2x. In my case I need to add backgrounds and for both 4-4s and 5-5s phones the images are 2x also is not showing an option for the 6/7 and is also 2x.

My question to guys is how can add the assets for every screen size in my xcassest file.

I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: You are confusing size with resolution. 1x, 2x, and 3x are about screen resolution. There is no such thing as having different _size_ images for difference screen sizes.

Comment: See for example my explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41903656/341994

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is "missing". Screens can come in different *resolutions*, and all possibilities appear in the screen shot. So every image in your app will come in three versions, and slots are provided for all of them. (You should use "Universal" unless the images for iPhone and iPad are truly different from one another, i.e. different *content*.)

As for image *size*, just use a size that works with the largest screen and permit the image view to scale it down as needed (or, for less memory waste, scale it down in code yourself at runtime).